# Can I possibly use submit type of button with onclick function of javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowNewProfessionalWindow", "UpdateOrganizationUID"))
{
     <div class="divContent">
    <h5>Organization UID:</h5> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Org_UID)
         <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="SubmitQuery()" class="login-button" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />   
}

<script>
       function SubmitQuery() {
         var txtOrg_UID = $('#Org_UID').val();                          
         var grid = $('#UpdateOrganizationUIDGrid').data('tGrid');
         grid.rebind({
         orgUID: txtOrg_UID
         });
       }

    </script>
```

because when i click the button it goes to beginform then after that it goes to SubmitQuery() but the value of txtOrg_UID is missing.

Comment: your code looks fine just check if ID generated in view source of the text box is same as what you have used. Return false from SubmitQuery

Comment: how to return false from submitQuery?